# How to set the default collation of a table?

Tags: mysql

I am asked to set all table's `default COLLATE to utf8_bin`. How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to do this?

One at a time, I'm afraid...

```
alter table <some_table> convert to character set utf8 collate utf8_bin;
```

There's no bulk method, unless you feel like using `mysqldump` to get the whole DB out, edit the resulting dump to add the required collation and then reimporting the whole DB again.

Comment: `convert to` might be the wrong choice if the table's character data is in utf8 already.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT("ALTER TABLE ", TABLE_NAME," COLLATE utf8_bin") AS    String
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA="YourDatabaseName"
AND TABLE_TYPE="BASE TABLE"
```

One query to rule all,just run the result of this query.

Answer (score 0):

```
        ALTER TABLE <table name> COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

If you also need to update the existing character encoding (unlikely by the sounds of things), you can use:

```
      ALTER TABLE <table name> CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
```